# Is it possible to Stop jqGrid row(s) from being selected and/or highlighted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jquery-1.3.2

I've looked at the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs) but I've been unable to find an answer.  Is there a way to prevent a row from being highlighted when selected?  That or even a way to stop the row being selected at all.   I like the "hoverrows: true" option, but ideally I would like to stop a row from being selected on-click.

Thanks,

**Update:**
I've been able to "hackily" implement something which seems to be an interim fix.  I don't really like it at all and would idealy like a better solution, if there is one...

I have found that if I pass the option

```
onSelectRow: function(rowid, status) {
    $('#'+rowid).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
}
```

when I instantiate the jqGrid, I can strip the highlight when it is added.

Is there another, more ideal, way to do this?

Comment: Just curious: All rows, rows meeting a specific criteria (i.e., "odd" rows), or a specific single row?

Comment: any row which is clicked on.  the natural behavior of jqGrid is to apply the css class `ui-state-highlight` to a row, when it is clicked.  I wish to stop this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly the way I was trying to do it, I just couldn't find the right event to hook off.  Thanks.

Comment: Also be sure to match casing. `beforeselectrow` does not work.

Comment: What sucks about using this implementation you then disable onCellSelect :(

Comment: It doesn't gray out the row, just stops the selection.  Added a better and easier answer below using the rowattr callback instead of the beforeSelectRow callback.

Answer (score 7):

If you, like me, have a gazillion jqGrids and don't want to override onSelectRow for every single one, here's a global version of Reigel's solution that worked nicely for me:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
    onSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
        $('#'+rowid).parents('table').resetSelection();
    }
});
```

Comment: Very nice. I think only people who have a whole bunch of these things hanging around will appreciate your answer +1

Comment: This is a great answer. using resetSelection allows you to preserve the onSelectRow functionality and still clear the selection (I have a custom checkbox implementation that also toggles the checkbox on row click; this allows my code to keep working without the nasty selection color :))

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
onSelectRow: function(rowid, status) {
    $("#grid_id").resetSelection(); //Resets (unselects) the selected row(s). Also works in multiselect mode.
}
```

you can read documentations [here](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm). Hope it helps you...

Comment: Slightly more accurate than my solution.  Thanks.

Comment: This is useful when you want to perform certain actions and then reset the selection. Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could address this in the CSS directly.  Just override the values for ui-state-highlight for your specific table

```
#table_id tr.ui-state-highlight {
  border: inherit !important;
  background: inherit !important;
  color: inherit !important;
}

#table_id tr.ui-state-highlight a {
  color: inherit !important;
}

#table_id tr.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {
  background-image: inherit !important;
}
```

I used the value `inherit` just as an example - you will likely need to copy some values from your theme.css to make this work.

Comment: Thank's, I'll give this a shot in the morning and get back to you.

Comment: For browser compatibility sakes I'm going to dodge this implementation.  However it does seem quite nice to hide this problem in the css.  Thanks anyway +1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the rowattr callback:

```
rowattr: function (rowData,currentObj,rowId) {
    if (rowData.SomeField=="SomeValue") { 
        return {"class": "ui-state-disabled"};
    }
},
```

This also grays out the row and disables the selection.