# Struts 2 jqGrid beforeSelectRow stopping

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery-grid

How can I apply this code on the jquery struts2 grid:

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
    return false;
}
```

I found the solution for my problem on this thread: [Is it possible to Stop jqGrid row(s) from being selected and/or highlighted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148135/is-it-possible-to-stop-jqgrid-rows-from-being-selected-and-or-highlighted)

but is for the original javascript jqGrid version .

Comment: What version of struts2-jquery-plugin are you using?

Comment: Version struts2-jquery-plugin-3.2.1.jar and struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.2.1.jar

Comment: Use latest version of plugin and see if you can use that code with it.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try

Comment: @AleksandrM is not working