# Disable row select in jqGrid on right click

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

In jqGrid, I am currently disabling row select with the following:

```
beforeSelectRow: function() {
     return false;
}
```

This works fine for left clicking. However, I noticed it's not firing the `beforeSelectRow` event handler and still selecting the row when I right click. This is a problem for me since I'm implementing a custom context menu.

I am able to get around this with what asker himself admitted is a hack found here:
[Is it possible to Stop jqGrid row(s) from being selected and/or highlighted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148135/is-it-possible-to-stop-jqgrid-rows-from-being-selected-and-or-highlighted)

Is there any other, less hacky way to do this?

Thanks!

**Update**

It appears this is only a problem with subgrids. Please refer to this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/iacii/MCk7W/). You'll notice left clicking does not select the row but right clicking does.

(I took the lazy way out and stole this example from an answer to a different question provided by Oleg.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to disable the row select, you can config `onSelectRow` to return `false`, this will block both left click and right click.

```
onSelectRow: function() {
     return false;
}
```

To force unselect row on right click:

```
onRightClickRow: function () {
    grid.jqGrid('resetSelection');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this exact code as you can see in my question. It must be this doesn't work in subgrids. Please see my update.

Comment: @iacii Updated. hope it helps.

Comment: What is the need to return `false`?