# jqGrid - suppress row selection on right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In jqGrid, I want to disable row selection on right click. But, want to have the normal behavior (row selection on left click) enabled.

I tried to disable row selection on right click using the following code, but it does not have any effect,

```
onRightClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
   return false;
}
```

Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/235/

**Expectation:**

- Row should not be selected or deselected (if previously selected) on right click in a jqGrid.

I am using jqGrid  4.6.0. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what this post suggests: [Disable row select in jqGrid on right click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084214/disable-row-select-in-jqgrid-on-right-click)

https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/236/

```
onRightClickRow: function () {
    grid.jqGrid('resetSelection');
    return false;
}
```

It works, but just from playing around with it I noticed it unselects the previously selected row, which might not be ideal. If that's not a problem than this should be sufficient!

**EDIT**

If you want to maintain the previously selected row, you'll have to do something a little different.

https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/239/

```
jQuery("sg1").unbind("contextmenu");
```

or

```
jQuery("#sg1").jqGrid({
    //Parameters
}).unbind("contextmenu");
```

This works, but disables the onRightClickRow event entirely.

Comment: I looked at that post, but as I said, I need to preserve the previous selection. Basically, right click should not select or deselect a row.

Comment: Oh I missed that line.  I'll keep looking!

Comment: `jQuery("#sg1").unbind("contextmenu");` visually works but disables the onRightClickRow event entirely.  Do you need it to work while still capturing the click event?

Comment: I am not using any context menu in my grid. Let me try that.

Comment: Please update your answer with the last suggestion. It helped in disabling the row selection on right click. Fiddler of my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/239/. Thank you :)